# CURDATE() function like in mysql for mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Have seen that `new Date()` will display the current date with time. But I need only date part.

```
 new Date()
ISODate("2015-06-11T06:49:17.684Z")
```

I need only date part--> `ISODate("2015-06-11T00:00:00.000Z")`

Below is the sample data:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("55743942789a9abe7f4af40e"),
  "msisdn": "9xxxxxxxxx",
  "act_date": ISODate("2014-09-16T00:00:00Z"),
  "date": ISODate("2015-06-07T00:00:00Z"),
  "recharge": {
    "recharge_amt": 100,
    "rechargetype": "WEB"
  },
  "voice": {
    "local_og_mou": 4,
    "local_other_mobile_og_mou": 18,
    "nld_og_mou": 10,
    "nld_other_mobile_og_mou": 3
  },
  "gprs_usage": {
    "total_access_count": 1,
    "total_datavolume_mb": 63
  },
  "sms": {
    "freesms": 0,
    "local_sms_count": 0,
    "nat_sms_count": 2,
    "inter_sms_count": 0
  }
}
```

Need to Fetch current day data based on date field.
Is there any `CURDATE()` function like in mysql for mongoDB?

Comment: @chridam Through you could use "upsert" to insert, the `$currentDate` is an **exact** timestamp and not rounded like the question asks.

Comment: Maybe we lack of some context here: in which kind of MongoDB query you need that rounded date ? Or is it a "general JavaScript" question ? (In that eventuality, I took the liberty add the JavaScript tag -- feel free to remove it)

Comment: Below is the sample data.



{ "_id" : ObjectId("55743942789a9abe7f4af40e"), "msisdn" : "9xxxxxxxxx", "act_date" : ISODate("2014-09-16T00:00:00Z"), "date" : ISODate("2015-06-07T00:00:00Z"), "recharge" : { "recharge_amt" : 100, "rechargetype" : "WEB" }, "voice" : { "local_og_mou" : 4, "local_other_mobile_og_mou" : 18, "nld_og_mou" : 10, "nld_other_mobile_og_mou" : 3 }, "gprs_usage" : { "total_access_count" : 1, "total_datavolume_mb" : 63 }, "sms" : { "freesms" : 0, "local_sms_count" : 0, "nat_sms_count" : 2, "inter_sms_count" : 0 } }


Need to Fetch current day data based on date field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can "round" the date object to the current day:

```js
new Date( new Date().valueOf() - new Date().valueOf() % ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) )
```

Of course, there are varying language dependant ways to "round" your date, but this is a JavaScript way.

Comment: Hi 

Got result with the below query.Thanks 


db.colection.find({"date":new Date( new Date().valueOf() - new Date().valueOf() % ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) )})

Answer (score 0):

Just in order to be a little bit more robust, I would use *range query* instead of an exact match to query dates (imagine some client having updated the data using `$currentDate` for example):

```
// @user3561036 code:
var theDate = new Date( new Date().valueOf() - new Date().valueOf() % ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 )

// One day later:
var theDayAfter = new Date(theDate.valueOf() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)


// Search for date in the range `[theDate, theDayAfter)`
db.colection.find({"date": { $gte: theDate, $lt: theDayAfter } })
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could take is using the **[momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/)** library, in particular the [`.startOf('day')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) method:

```
var currentDate = moment().startOf('day').toDate();

db.colection.find({"date": currentDate})
```